# How to get a redirection url that appears temporarily before routing to another url using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing

I have this url I am using to get a code. I, then, need to use this code and get the token. When I visit this url `mysite.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ewrtergdgdfg324324242&redirect_uri=myNewUrl/oauth-check`, I get directed to a login page.

There when I enter the credentials and press login, a temporary url `myNewUrl/oauthcheck?code=dsfdsfs3242343242423` appears with a code (which I need to extract) and then redirects to my application's home page(myNewUrl). I need to extract the "code" from this temporary url. But this url just appears and disappears. I tried the below code to get this code. When I try getCurrentUrl, I'm only getting the new home page url. Not this temporary url.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "/Users/me/Documents/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("mysite.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ewrtergdgdfg324324242&redirect_uri=https://myNewUrl/oauth-check");

        ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("login_email").sendKeys("myuser@mysite.com");
        ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("login_password").sendKeys("password");
        ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'btn btn--primary btn--regular login-btn')]").click();

        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

How can I extract the "code" from this temporary url? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not able to load your mentioned URL. It is saying Page Not Found - 404 Error Page
The page you are looking for () is not here.

Comment: agreed with @mayooran , it's impossible to address your issue unless we have html code or a live website to test

Comment: As this is an internal project this url is not accessible from outside. @cruisepandey hope you got my question. I need to capture the intermediate url that appears and vanishes before loading my homepage

Comment: @AutomatedOwl just need the idea :)

Comment: well you can open that particular URL in new tab/window and then try to get the source of it. you can use actions class for that , and remember to switch to new tab to get the source.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please explain it a bit descriptively.

Comment: can you open that temp URL in new windows or in new tab ?

Comment: When I press the login button this intermediate url appears and it just vanishes in micro seconds. Appears in the browser and even before I click it loads the home page url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for any idea then it might be some ajax interceptor using selenium or capturing network tab logs in console.
May be you can get your URL using some sort of javascript code for ajax intercepting or get it by using following code to get network tab logs :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                   "D://ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE//Selenium-Demo//src//main//resources//drivers//chromedriver-2.35.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        String scriptToExecute = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
        String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
        System.out.println(netData);
```

I am not sure if it helps you but my approach is something like that only.
Hope that helps you.